# Log every API request and responsne in MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

I would like to log every request and response including parameters sent and responses as well such as within response body.

```
callModel.executionTime = (DateTime.UtcNow - started).ToString();
Stream streamToReadFrom = await request.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(streamToReadFrom, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
callModel.requestBody = streamWriter.ToString();
```

Above is some code i use to read request body but i get error stating cannot read response.

Any help in identifying a generic way to do this will be most appreciated.

Comment: I think action filter may be what you're looking for. https://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/controllers-and-routing/understanding-action-filters-cs